# Conservation laws - Airy's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm considering Airy equation $u_t+u_{xxx}=0$ and want to derive two
conservation laws for a solution $u(t; x)$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int{u}dx=0$$ and $$\frac{d}{dt}\int{u^2}dx=0$$
Using Fourier transform I have derive the solution formula, but stuck here.. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}
 \newcommand{\uu}{\,{\rm u}}$
\begin{align}
\totald{}{t}\int_{a}^{b}\uu^{2}\,\dd x&=\int_{a}^{b}2\uu\uu_{t}\,\dd x
=-2\int_{a}^{b}\uu\uu_{xxx}\,\dd x
=\left.\vphantom{\Large A}-2\uu\uu_{xx}\right\vert_{a}^{b}
+ 2\int_{a}^{b}\uu_{xx}\uu_{x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\left.\vphantom{\Large A}-2\uu\uu_{xx}\right\vert_{a}^{b}
+\int_{a}^{b}\partiald{\uu_{x}^{2}}{x}\,\dd x
=\bracks{-2\uu\uu_{xx} + \uu_{x}^{2}}_{a}^{b}
\end{align}

> $$
> \bracks{2\uu \uu_{xx} - \uu_{x}^{2}}_{a}^{b}
> +\totald{}{t}\int_{a}^{b}\uu^{2}\,\dd x = 0
> $$

Whenever $\ds{\bracks{2\uu\uu_{xx} - \uu_{x}^{2}}_{a}^{b} = 0}$ we'll have
$\ds{\int_{a}^{b}\uu^{2}\pars{x,t}\,\dd x}$ independent of $\ds{t}$.

Comment: Your derive is beautiful. But I think you missed a minus sign before the last term of your final result.

Comment: @lxy You are right. I just fixed it. Thanks.